# Uncaught reference error:False is not defined

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have the following call to javascript:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        this._BtAdd.Attributes.Add("onclick", "GXDualListBox_MoveDualList(" + sourceListId + ",  " + destListId + ",  " + selectedValuesId + ", false, true, "+ this._SortByDescription +");");
        this._BtRemove.Attributes.Add("onclick", "GXDualListBox_MoveDualList(" + destListId + ",  " + sourceListId + ",  " + selectedValuesId + ", false, false, " + this._SortByDescription + ");");

        if (!this._PostBackOnAll)
        {
            this._BtAddAll.Attributes.Add("onclick", "GXDualListBox_MoveDualList(" + sourceListId + ",  " + destListId + ",  " + selectedValuesId + ", true, true, " + this._SortByDescription + " );");
            this._BtRemoveAll.Attributes.Add("onclick", "GXDualListBox_MoveDualList(" + destListId + ",  " + sourceListId + ",  " + selectedValuesId + ", true, false, " + this._SortByDescription + " );");
        }

        // Check if user can double-click on listbox item to move it
        if (this._AllowDblClick)
        {
            this._LstSource.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "GXDualListBox_MoveDualList(" + sourceListId + ",  " + destListId + ",  " + selectedValuesId + ", false, true, " + this._SortByDescription + " );");
            this._LstDestination.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "GXDualListBox_MoveDualList(" + destListId + ",  " + sourceListId + ",  " + selectedValuesId + ", false, false, " + this._SortByDescription + " );");
        }
    }
```

this._SortByDescription  is bool which would be false in this case. The javascript is as follows:

```
function GXDualListBox_MoveDualList(srcList, destList, selectedValues, moveAll, isAdd,sortByDescription) 
{

if ((srcList.selectedIndex == -1) && (moveAll == false)) {
    return;
}
newDestList = new Array(destList.options.length);

for (var len = 0; len < destList.options.length; len++) {
    if (destList.options[len] != null) {
        newDestList[len] = new Option(destList.options[len].text, destList.options[len].value, destList.options[len].defaultSelected, destList.options[len].selected);
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i < srcList.options.length; i++) {
    if (srcList.options[i] != null && (srcList.options[i].selected == true || moveAll)) {
            newDestList[len] = new Option(srcList.options[i].text, srcList.options[i].value, srcList.options[i].defaultSelected, srcList.options[i].selected);
            len++;
    }
}

if (sortByDescription) {
    newDestList.sort(GXDualListManager_CompareOptionValues);   
    newDestList.sort(GXDualListManager_CompareOptionText);  
}


for (var j = 0; j < newDestList.length; j++) {
    if (newDestList[j] != null) {
        destList.options[j] = newDestList[j];
    }
}   
}

if (isAdd)
    buildSelectedList(destList, selectedValues);
else
    buildSelectedList(srcList, selectedValues);
}
```

When I hard code this._SortByDescription as 'false' in the javascript call, it works. But replacing 'false' with this._SortByDescription results in error. Also I observed while debugging that the javascript receives the value of this._SortByDescription as 'False' instead of 'false'. Not sure if this matters. 
I am working on javascript for the first time. Please help.

Comment: Yes it's metters because `false` != `False` on JavaScript. Did you event tried to change it? Fix that and then you go.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown thanks for replying. I am setting the value of _SortByDescription as 'false'. When the javascript is called I can see it sending 'false' and not 'False'

Comment: Well, that's not what your error message is saying. What you see on the generated source-code?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown The generated source code is: 'GXDualListBox_MoveDualList(......, true, true, False );' 
I apologize for the bad formatting. But in the code I can see the value of  this._SortByDescription set as 'false' but somehow javascript receives it as 'False'

Comment: What about to try `this._SortByDescription.ToLowerCase()` ??

Comment: How its bool if you're concatenating it on a string directly?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown  converting to Lower Case solved it. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind, I have posted it as an answer to you to accept.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try converting to lower case:

```
this._SortByDescription.ToLower();
```

If the property of type `bool`:

```
this._SortByDescription.ToString().ToLower();
```

Comment: In Javascript, do true and false NEED to be lowercase? I got the same thing just now, but,  Uncaught ReferenceError: TRUE is not defined. I'm so used to making them capitalized in PHP.

Comment: @taco yeah, it is case sensitive, as well everything on JavaScript. Try by yourself on dev tools console of your browser. Type `TRUE`, `True` and `true`. You will see that only the last one is ok. Its a little diferent as PHP.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this._SortByDescription.ToString().ToLower();`? I get `'bool' does not contain a definition for 'ToLower' and no extension method 'ToLower' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` otherwise. Even if it is enclosed in strings `"sending(a, b, " + this._SortByDescription.ToLower() + ", d)"`, like so.

Comment: Came here to say the same thing. ToLower() only works on a string (so the approved answer should be edited unless I'm missing something).

Answer (score 1):

You could also define "True" and "False" in the beginning of your function/JS. It may seem tedious, but it worked for me.

```
function xxx {
    var True = true;
    var False = false;

    // code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed, it is `False` in the land of `c#`, but `false` in `javascript`.  You just have to rejig your code so that it is returning the LC version.

```
this._SortByDescription ? "true" : "false"
```

I faced something similar.  I had scriptlets in my ASP pages and this failed for the same reason:

```
isSubSpeciesAspect = <%=Model.aspect.ToLower() === "subspecies"%>;
```

In the generated JS this came out as:

```
isSubSpeciesAspect = True;
```

I just had to move things around to fix this problem:

```
isSubSpeciesAspect = ("<%=Model.aspect.ToLower()%>" === "subspecies");
```